# Displaying results in subform only works for first query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to build the front end for a Mysql database application using linked tables in MS Access. Currently, I have a button on a form which executes a query that allows the user to search for records by a person's name. On the form, there is a subform which displays the results of the executed query.

My problem is that whenever I open the form, the subform only displays the query results for the first time the query is executed. If I try to search for another name, it will open the results set in a separate sheet and not update my subform.

How can I get the subform to update on every search?

Disclaimer: I am new to Access and do not know any VBA code.

Query:

```
SELECT employees.FNAME, employees.LNAME, access.NAME, access.USERNAME, access.CREATED_BY, access.ACCESS_GRANTED, access.ACCESS_TERMINATED, access.ADMIN
FROM employees INNER JOIN access ON EMPLOYEES.ID = ACCESS.ID
WHERE (((employees.FNAME) Like "*" & Forms![Form1]!FNameTxt & "*"));
```

[Picture of my form after query with name "chase" is executed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAHDC.png)

Comment: Could you give us a bit more information please.  So you have a button on form that executes a query - can we see the code/macro behind the button?  I assume the query is returning the correct data, so it must be something to do with the button or you're using the wrong type of query - a SELECT when you should be using INSERT - can we see the SQL for the query?

Comment: I believe the problem lies in the macro. Currently, it is `Open Query`, Query name: `List by FName`, view: `datasheet`, Data Mode: `Edit`. Do I need to add something to it to make it display on the form more than one time?

Comment: By the sounds of it your query should be used as the `Record Source` for the form and the button should apply a filter to the records.  Can't be sure though without seeing it.

Comment: What do you need to see exactly? I have edited a picture of my form with the results of a "first" query into my original post. If I were to click "search by first name" again, it would open the results in a different tab instead of showing them in the form below.

Comment: Don't use Open Query, use Requery. However, since I use only VBA, not quite sure how to code in Macro. Instead of [Enter employee name] which will trigger an input popup, reference control on form for the input parameter. The ID's should be in a JOIN clause not WHERE clause.

Comment: I've updated the query to reference the a textbox on the page with the subform. I was having problems with the JOIN in access, so I used the e.id = a.id in the WHERE clause as a workaround for the time being. I am more concerned with being able to refresh the table data currently.

Comment: What was the difficulty with JOIN? If it works in WHERE should work in JOIN. I do find it odd that the linking is on two ID fields. I hope they are not both autonumber. Should the access.ID primary key link to an employees.accessID foreign key? Maybe should be one table.

Comment: Hm I edited the query based on your suggestion and it is getting the correct result. I don't remember the exact problem that Access had before, but it was something wrong with my JOIN clause. EMPLOYEE has id as autoincrement PK, Access has composite key ID,NAME,USERNAME where ID is reference to PK in EMPLOYEE, NAME is reference to the PK of SYSTEMS table and USERNAME is the username of that employee for that system. (username is also part of the PK because an employee can have more than one account for a system.)

Comment: Name is a reserved word and advise not to use reserved words as names for anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never use dynamic parameterized query. I would use VBA code to set Filter and FilterOn properties, like:

`Me.Filter = "[FName] LIKE '*" & Me.cbxFNames & "*'"
Me.FilterOn = True`

If you prefer dynamic parameterized query the VBA would be: `Me.Requery`

If code is behind the main form then need to reference subform through container control. Recommend giving the container control a name different from the object it holds, like ctrEmps

`Me.ctrEmps.Requery`

The real trick is figuring out what event to put code into.

Comment: I was not able to directly find the solution with your answer, but it put me on the right path, as well as fixing other problems I had. The reason my results were opening in a different tab: I had set a macro on the "query execution" button that opened the results in a new tab. I set a Macro to requery the subform after the textbox that the parameter is entered in is updated. Thank you for your help.